# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'[flutter]

Tags: api, flutter, dart, gradle, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an flutter e-commerce app for both Android and IOS users. When I run my code, its shows an resource error, I couldn't find the answers.

````
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\JEYASRI.A\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_foodapp\build\file_picker\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-15:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 47s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Exception: The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.```
````

Comment: Hi, please update the post with code causing the error

Comment: Could you please share your Android build gradle setting (version) you have in your project?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you are getting the following error:

```
 AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.
```

The error is stating that the element  is not being recognized by Android Gradle Plugin.

[**Android 11 introduced `<queries>`**](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility) as a manifest element and older versions of the Android Gradle Plugin do not have this element.

So it could be that you are using an **Android Gradle Plugin** which does not allow the  element.

There are some series of patch versions released by Google in order to fix this error **(`3.3.3`, `3.4.3`, `3.5.4`, `3.6.4` and `4.0.1`)**.

So please upgrade your build gradle version to one from the above list.

Android Studio 4.1 or higher, with a matching
Android Gradle Plugin (e.g `4.1.*` series) does recognize  manifest element so they don't face these types of errors.

Have a look into [the Android Developers Blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/07/preparing-your-build-for-package-visibility-in-android-11.html).